# How do I display images from Google Drive on a react front-end website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, google-drive-api

I want to upload some photos in my Google Drive and would like me to display those photos. I'm actually using React.js right now and I'm really new to programming. I just wanna display the photos and have the specific date related to the photos. I'm searching on google and youtube and I still have no clear answers.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

**1)** Obtain the public link of your uploaded google drive image:

```
   my case: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_aPIblL-tTtWKAADSSADASDNIloPB4QNlfFcl-/view?usp=sharing
```

**2)** Extract the id from the link:

```
   my case: 1_aPIblL-tTtWKAADSSADASDNIloPB4QNlfFcl-
```

**3)** Use the following url structure in react:

```
 <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=INSERT_HERE_YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_IMAGE_ID" alt="drive image"/>
```

**4)** Result:

```
 <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_aPIblL-tTtWKAADSSADASDNIloPB4QNlfFcl-" alt="drive image"/>
```

For further doubts watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iajv8y-6n3Q that I made.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Go to your Google Drive and Share the link of photos in a public mode.

Then copy the id of your photos link.

Replace the ID's of your photo urls => [https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id='your](https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=%27your) photo link id'

Then Copy the Above by replacing ID and Paste it in Img Src of React Js App.

Then Run React Js App

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  return(
    <div>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id='your photo link id'" alt="image" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If Img tag don't work, try to use this

```
<img src={require('https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id='your photo link id').default} />
```

I Hope it works. Note my export view thumnail size, you can change the size according to your style requirement.